# How to build ar Z6 (TR-8R) riot control baton for 75114 (First Order Stormtrooper)?

Tags: star-wars, moc

Set 75114 has two guns but I would like my stormtrooper to have the iconic [melee weapon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Z6_riot_control_baton?file=Z6RCB-VD.jpg).

[image]

How can I build one?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Chima sword](http://rebrickable.com/parts/11103):

[image]

Perhaps with the [gun/torch](https://img.rebrickable.com/parts/86208) as a handle:

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion, and maybe add 1 or 2 1x1 brick, round in Trans Red in between for the body of the gun.